# How to pin blocks to the left side of the container using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Can anybody explaine me how to move block to the left side when the screen becomes smaller?

```
    .limited-offer-box
        display: flex
        flex-direction: row
        justify-content: space-around
        flex-wrap: wrap
```

[image]

In my case I need move the book "The book thief' (and other books when the screen will become smaller) to left side and not on the center
Like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide a runnable version?

Comment: Just remove `justify-content: space-around` and and give children a margin. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex` in correct way, considering the post, I can create something like this:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/qcx7ptL0/10/) to playaround.

```css
.MainDiv {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ChildDiv {
  margin: 10px;
}

.ChildDiv img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
</div>
```

> To make the `MainDiv` to the center:

```css
.MainDiv {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.ChildDiv {
  margin: 10px;
}

.ChildDiv img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
  <div class="ChildDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `display: inline-block` on the children in this scenario to "use flex in correct way" ;)

Comment: oops, I was adding code, I didn't check the code! my bad, I will take that out :) thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Manjuboyz one more question else, how to set whole container to the center? Because in this case it isn't on the center

Comment: There are many ways to handle that, I can try to put one of the way.

Comment: here is the sample snippet created for you, this may help you. https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/qcx7ptL0/16/

Comment: @Manjuboyz excuse me, one more and the last question: also how i can set content (blocks with images) on the center in your case at the "MainDiv"

Comment: the whole content into the center? if so the fiddle link I shared in comments is doing exactly what you need, it places the complete `MainDiv` to the center of the page.

Comment: I have added what you asked in answer, you can view that answer in full page to validate the `MainDiv` is in the center of the page.

Comment: @Manjuboyz you misunderstand me, how i can centered contet of MainDiv, because as you can see, images with cats are left,but not at the center of parent's block

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off using `grid` instead of `flexbox` for your use case.

Try using this in your CSS:

```css
.limited-offer-box {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 400px));
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

If not, you can try using `align-items: start;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `justify-content:space-around` to `justify-content:flex-start` and add a margin to your elements.